# TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type uint8 of argument 'x'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Packages Version:

- Tensorflow==2.5
- Python==3.8
- Keras==2.3

Here is the code:

```
# Pipe Line

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test), (x_val, y_val) = (X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test), (X_val, Y_val)

def model_seg():
  
  # Convolution Layers (BatchNorm after non-linear activation)
  
  img_input = Input(shape= (192, 256, 3))
  x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv1')(img_input)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn1')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv2')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn2')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
  x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv3')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn3')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv4')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn4')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
  x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv5')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn5')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(128, (4, 4), padding='same', name='conv6')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn6')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
  x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv7')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn7')(x)
  x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv8')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn8')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
  x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv9')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn9')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu', name='fc1')(x)
  x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu', name='fc2')(x)
  
  # Deconvolution Layers (BatchNorm after non-linear activation)
  
  x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv1')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn19')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = UpSampling2D()(x)
  x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv2')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn12')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv3')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn13')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = UpSampling2D()(x)
  x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (4, 4), padding='same', name='deconv4')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn14')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv5')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn15')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = UpSampling2D()(x)
  x = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv6')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn16')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv7')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn20')(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = UpSampling2D()(x)
  x = Conv2DTranspose(16, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv8')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn17')(x)
  x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
  x = Activation('relu')(x)
  x = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv9')(x)
  x = BatchNormalization(name='bn18')(x)
  x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
  pred = Reshape((192,256))(x)
  
  model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=pred)
  
  model.compile(optimizer= Adam(lr = 0.003), loss= [jaccard_distance], metrics=[iou])
  
  hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs= 300, batch_size= 16,validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1)
  
  model.save("model.h5")
  
  accuracy = model.evaluate(x=x_test,y=y_test,batch_size=16)
  print("Accuracy: ",accuracy[1])
```

Gives me this error in type conversion and I don't know how to fix it:

```
return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name)
D:\road-damage\road-damage-detection\rdd\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py:6248 mul
    _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
D:\road-damage\road-damage-detection\rdd\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py:555 _apply_op_helper
    raise TypeError(

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type uint8 of argument 'x'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, there's a tensor that is floats and a tensor that is integers, and it's not sure which one the result should be.

The architecture of your network does not tell us much; it is most likely to do with the way your data is being prepared.

If it is OK to treat your X and Y as floats, try explicitly converting them to floats like this before passing them to fit:

```
x_train = x_train.astype(np.float)
x_test = x_test.astype(np.float)
y_train = y_train.astype(np.float)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.float)
```